# Maxmind's GeoLite2 Continent code

Tags: php, geoip, maxmind

I'm using MaxMind's free [GeoLite2 database](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/).
According to their [code](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php#web-service-client), I can get the country's ISO code.
`print($record->country->isoCode . "\n"); // 'US'`
But how do I get the continent code ?
I'm more specifically looking for EU detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EU**

The list of EU (European Union) countries is:

- AT, Austria
- BE, Belgium
- BG, Bulgaria
- CR, Croatia
- CY, Republic of Cyprus
- CZ, Czech Republic
- DK, Denmark
- EE, Estonia
- FI, Finland
- FR, France
- DE, Germany
- GR, Greece
- HU, Hungary
- IE, Ireland
- IT, Italy
- LV, Latvia
- LI, Lithuania
- LU, Luxembourg
- MT, Malta
- NL, Netherlands
- PL, Poland
- PT, Portugal
- RO, Romania
- SK, Slovakia
- SI, Slovenia
- SP, Spain
- SE, Sweden
- GB, United Kingdom

example of what I use:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE'])) {
  $cc=$_SERVER['GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE'];
} else {
  $cc='??';
}
$eu=array('AT', 'BE', 'BG', 'HR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DK', 'EE', 'FI', 'FR', 'DE', 'GR', 'HU', 'IE', 'IT', 'LV', 'LT', 'LU', 'MT', 'NL', 'PL', 'PT', 'RO', 'SK', 'SI', 'SP', 'SE', 'GB');
if (in_array($cc,$eu)) {
   //inside EU
} else {
   //outside EU
}
```

**EEA**

Depending on what you seek to do (considering this is asked after GDPR became enforceable), you might want to test for EEA (European Economic Area) instead.

The EEA is:

- all EU members
- NO, Norway
- IS, Iceland
- LI, Liechtenstein

This is what I use with the full geoip:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE'])) {
  $cc=$_SERVER['GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE'];
} else {
  $cc='??';
}
$eea=array('AT', 'BE', 'BG', 'HR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DK', 'EE', 'FI', 'FR', 'DE', 'GR', 'HU', 'IE', 'IT', 'LV', 'LT', 'LU', 'MT', 'NL', 'PL', 'PT', 'RO', 'SK', 'SI', 'SP', 'SE', 'GB', 'NO', 'IS', 'LI');
if (in_array($cc,$eea)) {
   //inside EEA
} else {
   //outside EEA
}
```

**Special cases**

You need to deal with a number of special cases that depending on your intended use are to be included or not:

**Part of the EU, but with their own ISO 2 letter code**

- GI, Gibraltar (~UK)
- AX, Åland Islands (~Finland)

Note there are more of these, but they have no ISO country code of their own ...

These part of the EU and EEA, and have their own 2 letter country code.

**Outermost regions**

- GF, French Guiana (~France)
- GP, Guadeloupe (~France)
- MQ, Martinique (~France)
- YT, Mayotte (~France)
- RE, Réunion (~France)
- MF, Saint Martin (~France)

It gets complex with these, you should really read up on each for the specific reason you seek to define the EU if they're in or out. Also note that these tend to change sometimes without all that much press coverage.

**Overseas countries and territories**

There's even more of these, but they should not be considered part of the EU for most use cases, still do check them out if you have specific reasons.

**Enclaves**

These tend to not have their own country code, but sometimes for some purposes can have different rules applied to them nonetheless.

Examples are isolated parts of e.g. Germany or Spain, but are located inside e.g. Switzerland or Morocco.

**EFTA**

For completeness: Switzerland (CH) is neither a member of the EU nor of the EEA, but it is a member of the EFTA (European Free Trade Association).

**Micro states**

Liechtenstein is member of the EEA, but there's a few other that are neither part of the EU nor the EEA. Still, for practical reasons they do have various relations 
 with the EU (such as being part of the EURO zone, being inside the Schengen zone, charging VAT, etc.)

- AD, Andorra
- LI, Liechtenstein
- MC, Monaco
- SM, San Marino
- VC, Vatican City

**Continent**

If you do seek the continent you will need to add a lot more countries, and you'll have to deal with countries that are not solely in Europe (e.g. Turkey, Russia).

**Maxmind's "EU" country code**

Maxmind sometimes uses the country code "EU" when it cannot determine which country it actually is. This "EU" refers to Europe, not the European Union (for which the EU country code is actually reserved).

**More info:**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_member_state_territories_and_the_European_Union
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microstates_and_the_European_Union
https://dev.maxmind.com/faq/what-are-the-eu-europe-and-ap-asia-pacific-entries/

Comment: You may also want to include: AX (Åland Islands), GI (Gibraltar), GP (Guadeloupe), MF (Saint Martin), MQ (Martiniue), RE (Réunion), and YT (Mayotte). These are oversee territories of countries in the EU that have their own ISO country code. They are considered to be outermost regions of the EU.

Comment: You're right, depending on use they should be included. But it's quite tricky: some are part of the EU (and EEA) for purposes of the GDPR e.g. but not for purposes of VAT. 
Politicians: you can only trust them to make a mess.

Comment: Updated it to cover more of the exceptions and difficult edge cases. But it's really hard to get it 100% right unless you know what the list will be used for.

Comment: Nice update! I agree that it gets complicated quickly and is highly dependent on the specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for whether the country is a member state of the European Union, [MaxMind provides this](http://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-php/doc/v2.9.0/class-GeoIp2.Record.Country.html):

```
$record->country->isInEuropeanUnion
```

If you want the [continent code](http://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-php/doc/v2.9.0/class-GeoIp2.Record.Continent.html), you can get it with:

```
$record->continent->code
```

However, please note that not all countries in Europe are part of the European Union.

Comment: $record = $reader->city('165.72.200.11'); die($record->country->isInEuropeanUnion . "\n"); doesn't print anything

Comment: That IP does not have a country associated with it, only a continent. It isn't possible to say that it is in the European Union. As such `FALSE` is returned.